# Both "not equal" symbols isn't working on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good day, On my db, I have two tables(entities), one is named **stall** and the other is for **clients**. On the index page, I made a table(function) that would return the rows of the database entity, **stall** which foreignkey (**stallno**) values which are not present in the clients table.
For further details, the **stallno** is the primary key of the table **stall** and a *foreign key* on **clients**.

What I want to display is the number of stalls that is still available or yet to be occupied by clients. So I made a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.stallno, a.location, a.condition, b.stallno 
FROM stall a, clients b WHERE NOT (a.stallno<=>b.stallno);
```

I have a hundred number of stalls saved on the DB table **stall**. Right now, several numbers are being taken by the clients, these are 12,11,13,14,20,21,28,29 and 30 (thus was being saved at the clients table as the foreign key **stallno**)
So the once that should be displayed are those numbers which are not in this group. Like for example, Stall numbers: 1,2,10,35 etc (those remaining numbers).
That's why I've chose to use the not equal functions/symbols to get what I wanted. First query I've used was this:

```
SELECT a.stallno,a.location,a.condition, b.stallno 
FROM stall a, clients b WHERE a.stallno!=b.stallno
```

But this only displayed the entire rows including the values of **b.stallno** and duplicate it aswell. Not only that, it also display 0 numbers. Which is also part of b.stallno. What I want to display is the remaining number which are not connected with **b.stallno**. So I tried to use the DISTINCT function instead, on the hopes of omitting the 0 numbers. Which kinda worked, but still it duplicates the numbers (12,11,13,14,20,21,28,29 and 30) and the numbers which are yet to be taken (those apart from the given numbers). What I did is to try another query again. This time, the NOT function.

SELECT DISTINCT a.stallno, a.location, a.condition, b.stallno FROM stall a, tenant b WHERE NOT (a.stallno!=b.stallno)

But still, appears to be not working. even the <> giving me the same results.
Until I came across with this <=> symbol. Which is said to have worked as a not equal function. I tried it but with a slight difference to the first few statements. This time all the numbers from a.stallno (which is the PK to DB **stall**) displays all rows from 1-100.

Now, I came with the conclusion that perhaps these symbols for not equals <=>,!=,<> do not seem to work in DREAMWEAVER, or either PHPandMySQL. What d'you guys think?
Do you know something that would call the NOT EQUAL function.

Comment: `<=>` is not _not equal_. It's _null-safe equal_. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: You need to understand how JOINs work a bit better. You are requesting a cartesian product of the two tables (all possible combinations) and then filtering out just a part of the resulting records... and wrongly. Go with Lorenz's advice. You need a LEFT JOIN that just puts in the result matching rows or stalls with no clients... and then filter out the former. There are a lot of good tutorials on JOINs, you should have a look at some.

Answer (score 0):

The not equal sign in mysql is != . The problem is that you search in the wrong direction.

You should use an left join :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.stallno, a.location, a.condition
FROM stall a left join clients b ON a.stallno=b.stallno
WHERE b.stallno is null
```